# Why isn't my image showing in CSS background?

Tags: jquery, html, css, colorbox

I am using colorbox [here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb4/compliance.html).

When you click on a link inside the Accordian, on one of the links, it brings up the lightbox, but there's no image and there is one in some in-line CSS in the code. You can view the pop-up's html code [here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb4/content/ajax.html).

As you can see, the background image is there when you view the pop-up as a page. But, within the pop-up, it's clearly not there.

Ideas?

**Note:** Please stop down-voting this post. I really need help with this. I posted an update 5 minutes ago with code and thought that was good enough. If I'm not posting right, please let me know. I've read all the rules.

```
<div id='rule' style="background:url(../images/suo_seal.png) right center no-repeat #ececec; height:auto; width:700px; padding:30px;">
```

Comment: Why would you down-vote this? I need help with it! Jack Moore's website said to consult StackOverflow for assistance. Please explain!

Comment: Once your nice web dies, and we suppose SO will outlive it, this Question will be useless. Show some code, stick to the real problem, do some research effort before asking. Help us to help you!

Comment: Edit: 

I thought posting links to the code was just as good. My bad. 

Here is the in-line CSS: 

    `<div id='rule' style="background:url(../images/suo_seal.png) right center no-repeat #ececec; height:auto; width:700px; padding:30px;">`

And if you review this link [here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb4/content/ajax.html), you'll see the image is there, but it doesn't show up on the lightbox pop-up...

Comment: You should update your question with the code.

Comment: Having looked at your website, right-clicked the `#rule` element and clicked 'Inspect element' Chromium, navigating to the image ('open in another tab') leads to this page: http://webfro.gs/south/images/suo_seal.png So: I suspect that your URL is wrong.

Comment: That's odd... I did the exact same thing and ended up here: http://webfro.gs/south/kb4/images/suo_seal.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to your image is wrong. ../images is a folder one level higher than the location of the current document. But your images folder is at the same level as the current document. Take the ../ out and the image will appear.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time with that. I missed it. We can thank DreamWeaver for that one. All I did was browse for the image and drop the files on my server. I will remember this.

Comment: Additionally, when I keep out that ../ from my local directory, the image doesn't show. It has to be there in order to show. But the only way it works on the server is if I remove the ../   Any ideas there?

Comment: Make sure that the file tree in your dev environment is the same as the file tree in your live environment.